# How to use Jobqueue in Python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, job-queue

I have able to make a bot very easily by reading the [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) but Jobqueue is not working as per it is written. The `run_daily` method uses a `datetime.time` object to send the message at a particular time but this code neither does its job of sending a message nor shows any errors. It just keeps running

```
    import datetime
    from telegram import bot
    from telegram.ext import Updater
    def callback_minute(bot, job):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=475838704, text='PlEaSe wOrK!')

    def main():
        updater = Updater()
        bot = updater.bot
        job = updater.job_queue

        dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

        job.run_daily(callback_minute, time=datetime.time(6,33,00))

        updater.start_polling()
        updater.idle()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this would help:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

def daily_job(bot, update, job_queue):
    """ Running on Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri = tuple(range(5)) """
    bot.send_message(chat_id=<YOUR CHAT ID>, text='Setting a daily notifications!')
    t = datetime.time(10, 00, 00, 000000)
    job_queue.run_daily(notify_assignees, t, days=tuple(range(5)), context=update)

def notify_assignees(bot, job):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=<CHAT ID>, text="Some text!")

updater = Updater(<BOT_TOKEN>)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('notify', daily_job, pass_job_queue=True))
updater.start_polling()
```

and say to bot `/notify`

Answer (score 4):

Simple usage example of [JobQueue Extention](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) from [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io)

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

def callback_alarm(bot, job):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=job.context, text='Wait for another 10 Seconds')

def callback_timer(bot, update, job_queue):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                      text='Wait for 10 seconds')
    job_queue.run_repeating(callback_alarm, 10, context=update.message.chat_id)

def stop_timer(bot, update, job_queue):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                      text='Stopped!')
    job_queue.stop()

updater = Updater("YOUR_TOKEN")
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', callback_timer, pass_job_queue=True))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('stop', stop_timer, pass_job_queue=True))

updater.start_polling()
```

the `/start` command will start the JobQueue and will send a message with an interval of 5 seconds, and the queue can be stopped by `/stop` command.

Comment: Hi , have you been able to solve this, tzinfo by default is UTC, so it doesnt match with IST?

Comment: @Shubh add 5h30min to it :)

Answer (score 3):

use below codes :

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, Updater

my_token = 'YOUR TOKEN'
updater = Updater(my_token, use_context=True)
job_queue = updater.job_queue

def send_message_job(context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id='@YOUR CHANELL ID',text='job executed')

job_queue.run_repeating(send_message_job,interval=10.0,first=0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember also to install the scheduler library upon which the telegram depends:

```
pip install APScheduler
```