# telegram bot api python run_daily method

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Hey i am trying to run a telegram bot on a daily base so i tried different things.

```
updater = Updater(<botkey>, use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.job_queue.run_daily(pollen, datetime.time(hour=20, minute=9), days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
dp.add_error_handler(error)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()

def pollen(update, context):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='text')
```

or

```
updater = Updater(<botkey>, use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', creatJobs, pass_job_queue=True, pass_chat_data=True))
dp.add_error_handler(error)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()

def pollen(update, context):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='text')


def creatJobs(update, context):
    new_job = context.job_queue.run_daily(pollen, datetime.time(hour=20, minute=9), days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), context=chat_id)
    context.chat_data['job'] = new_job
```

or

```
updater = Updater(<botkey>, use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', creatJobs, pass_job_queue=True, pass_chat_data=True))
dp.add_error_handler(error)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()

def pollen(update, context):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='text')

def creatJobs(update, context):
    context.job_queue.run_daily(reset, pollreset, days=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

but nothing works, i am developing on windows and python 3.8
imports always the same

```
import logging, re, datetime, time

import telegram
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Location
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler, CallbackQueryHandler)
```

Comment: Please describe the issue you are having/error you're receiving

Comment: @Hack5 thats also a problem i am reciving no error or somthing else its just not working. I put all days in the tupel of run daily and the current time and then happens nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Telegram Bot - run\_daily does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884051/python-telegram-bot-run-daily-does-not-work)

Answer (score 2):

**Due to a bug [click here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1693) Job_queue is skipping job if timezone is not provided for job.run_daily.**

Add timezone in your code it will run perfectly.

```
datetime.time(hour=6, minute=27, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
```

Refer the below code if you get any error.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import logging, datetime, pytz

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger()


def start(update, context):
    context.job_queue.run_daily(msg,
                                datetime.time(hour=6, minute=27, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')),
                                days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), context=update.message.chat_id)

def msg(context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=context.job.context, text='text')

def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    updater = Updater( < YOUR_TOKEN > , use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start, pass_job_queue=True))
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```